# For any $r, s \in \mathbb{N}$, show how to order the numbers $1, 2, \ldots , rs$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So that the resulting sequence has no increasing subsequence of length $\ge r$ and no decreasing subsequence of length $\ge s$.

Comment: Lousy way to treat a new contributor. Why not post comments instead to let OP know what's expected around here?

Comment: Now posted to (and closed on) MO, with no notice to either site of the post to the other: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342516/for-any-r-s-in-mathbbn-show-how-to-order-the-numbers-1-2-rs – that's an abuse of the system, Idk, please don't do that!

Answer (score 2):

$$s,s-1,s-2,\ldots,1,\quad  2s,2s-1,\ldots, s+1,\quad 3s,3s-1,\ldots $$
A decreasing sequence must stay within a block, an increasing sequence cannot have more than one term from the same block.

Comment: But this has both decreasing subsequences of length $s$ and increasing subsequences of length $r$. I think the question needs to be asked with $>$ instead of $\ge$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079113/a-sequence-of-rs-1-real-numbers-has-an-increasing-subsequence-of-length-r

Comment: you are correct Gerry, the question is asked with > instead of >=, but what I'm concerned with is that in class we only did a sequence of length n^2+1 and proved that it either has an increasing or decreasing sequence of n+1. r*s is in no way guaranteed to be written in the form of n^2+1 so I don't understand how I'm supposed to apply what we did in lecture

Comment: @IdkDk Have you looked at the link I gave in my comment? The question has been asked (correctly) and answered more than once on this website.