# For every large set $A\subset \mathbb{N},$ there is a concave subsequence of $A$ of length $k$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, pigeonhole-principle, ramsey-theory, erdos-conjecture

> Proposition: Suppose $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ is a large set in the sense
> that
>
> $$ \sum_{n\in A} \frac{1}{n} = \infty.$$
>
> Then there exists $a_1 < a_2 < \ldots < a_k,\ $ (not necessarily
> consecutive) members of $A,$  such that
>
> $$ a_k - a_{k-1} \leq a_{k-1} - a_{k-2} \leq \ldots \leq a_2 - a_1 $$
>
> for every $k\in\mathbb{N}.$
>
> In other words, for every $k,$ there is a subsequence of $A$ of length
> $k$ such that the differences (of consecutive members of the
> subsequence) are decreasing, also known as, the subsequence is *concave*.

From the ratio test, we have that, if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N} } $ is $A$ in (increasing) sequence form, then  $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left\lvert \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \right\rvert =1. $ Maybe this can be used to answer the question, but I don't see how straight away. But maybe it is a helpful fact to bear in mind.

My first thought to tackle this problem was to look at Erdos et al's results in bof's answer to my earlier question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4668840/given-increasing-sequence-of-numbers-what-is-guaranteed-min-length-the-longest). However, that question and bof's answer is about sequences with no concave *and* no convex sub-sequences, whereas this question is only about concave sub-sequences, or if we're trying to prove the contrapositive: sequences with *no* concave subsequence of length $k$, but *are* allowed to have convex sub-sequences of arbitrary length..

I wonder if we can show that sequences that do not contain concave sequences of arbitrary length are quasi-exponential/geometric in some sense? That would prove the contrapositive of the proposition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The affirmative answer to a [previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4744200/29156) means that for every $k$ no matter how large, $A$ will contain a quasi-arithmetic progression of length $k.$

Now note that every quasi-A.P. of length $k$ has a concave subsequence of length at least $\ \log_2 k - 1.\ $ For example, using the above theorem, we can find a quasi-arithmetic progression of $A$ of length $k=64.$ That is, there exists intervals $\ I_0,\ I_1,\ I_2,\ I_3,\ \ldots,\ I_{63}$ of equal width, such that $\ a_0\in I_0,\ a_1\in I_1,\ a_2\in I_2,\ a_3\in I_3,\  \ldots,\ a_{63} \in I_{63}.$  Then $a_0,\ a_{32},\ a_{32+16},\ a_{32+16+8},\ a_{32+16+8+4},\ a_{32+16+8+4+2}\ $ is a concave subsequence of $A,\ $ and we are done, since we can do all this for arbitrarily large $k,$ and  $\ \log_2 k - 1\to\infty\ $ as $\ k\to\infty.$